# How do I calculate the velocity dispersion of a galaxy given an integral field spectrograph?

Tags: spectroscopy, data-analysis, observatory

I couldn't find on the web how to get the velocity dispersion and velocity maps of galaxies from the 3D data cube that I get from the integral field spectrograph.

Comment: Could you please add some more detail? what is 3D data cube? For "integral field spectrograph" you mean the observation of the whole field of view of the instrument/satellite?

Answer (score 3):

If the 3D data cube is sufficiently highly resolved, try to find [Doppler shifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) in the [spectra](http://astronomy.nmsu.edu/nicole/teaching/ASTR505/lectures/lecture26/slide01.html) by looking for [typical absorption/emission lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-alpha). Doppler shifts correspond to [radial velocities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_velocity). Calculate the mean radial velocity, and e.g. the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of the radial velocities, as velocity dispersion.

The velocity dispersion of galaxies leads to a widening of spectral lines in comparison to a reference star. A couple of methods are discussed in [this paper](http://mnras.oxfordjournals.org/content/339/1/215.full.pdf), mostly some kind of [Fourier fitting, but direct fitting is used, too](http://cas.sdss.org/stripe82/en/help/docs/algorithm.asp?key=veldisp).

[Redshifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift) may contain a [gravitational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift) component.

[There exist data reduction software tools](http://p3d.sourceforge.net/).

[A paper](http://www.eso.org/~hkuntsch/papers/MNRAS_373_906.pdf) describing data reduction and velocity analysis using the [XOASIS tool](http://cral.univ-lyon1.fr/labo/oasis/download/).